# AVG (free) plus what?

Tags: security, avg-antivirus

I D/L'ed AVG free.  What other protection should I use? I am setting up a Win7 64bit system.

Comment: Why do you think you need other protection. That and the built in firewall should be sufficient. Either way this smells like an opinion question to me.

Comment: Smart and Safe Surfing Habits, maybe?  Leaving Windows behind and switching to Linux?  Depending on how you use your computer, and where you go on the internet, you might not even need AVG or Windows.  So, there's not really enough information to work with.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, if you supplement AVG with [Noscript](http://noscript.net/) and [Adblock+](http://adblockplus.org/en/) with some good browsing habits (I'm assuming that you'll be browsing the internet and everything), you should be safe for a good portion of the internet.

No firewall can protect you from the depth of uninformed internet browsing.

Answer (score 1):

The antivirus that I use for all my customers is [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/security-essentials).

It's a free Antivirus from Microsoft for genuine (legal) users of Windows XP, Vista and 7. It will also be available for Windows 8